# Android app runs slowly

Tags: android, drawable, lag

I am developing a really simple app on Android 5.0, but it lags all the time. There ist just a `textedit` and a button with a custom `drawable` instead of the normal button. The `drawable` is a 2000x2000 png file.
When I looked through the threads with the android device monitor I noticed the "Render Thread" takes up all the time. I don't know it's exact function. Does someone know where my error could be?

Sorry for no code example, I just don't know what could cause my lags and what I should therefor post.

Comment: What kind of Image is it? Is it possiable to make it small? What does your app do?

Comment: Are you on a device or an emulator? Emulators can dramatically slow down the execution of the application.

Comment: in addition keep the size of your images to the minimum. Have a look on the following link that shows the suggested size for images for each category of screen size. I think 2000x2000 is too big for any size screen.
   
   ` xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
    large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
    normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
    small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp`

from: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you load a bitmap, keep it in RAM only at the resolution you need
>   for the current device's screen, scaling it down if the original
>   bitmap is a higher resolution. Keep in mind that an increase in bitmap
>   resolution results in a corresponding (increase2) in memory needed,
>   because both the X and Y dimensions increase.

So, My advice, Please use **SMALL image size instead of LARGE** .

Comment: I was not sure, which size I should use instead, For a simple shape, can you give me an advice?

Comment: just resize and scale it down to height or width of the button view you want on the screen. may be slightly bigger to avoid blurring in case of larger screens.

Comment: @Jonas have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546642/android-slow-performance-using-a-big-image-in-imageview

Comment: Thank you, I scaled it to 400x400 and it works perfectly. I haven't thought, the image would have such an performance impact. Just out of curiousity, how often is the image loaded/used? I thought it would be loaded once in the beginning and then never again.

Comment: @Jonas Glad to hear .

Answer (score 1):

use different drawables(use asset studio) for different resolutions.Also use tinypng tool to reduce size of images.