# In android tabbed activity, the tab with the imageview loads slowly. Is there a better way to code imageview?

Tags: android, imageview

I am a beginner in android. I used a image of resolution 2048 * 1152 as the banner image below  in one of the tabs in tab activity. That tab stutters and hangs up and loads slowly when activated. I plan on using many images like amazon, ebay, etc. How to code the app efficiently so that it wont hang up or stutter when using a lot of images?

Comment: If its a server image then use `Glide` for load image efficiently with using `.override(width ,height)` which will resize your image.

Comment: I guess you have put all these images inside **drawable** folder. Just cut these images and put them inside respective **drawable-different-dpis** folders.

Comment: use vector drawable. it will reduce your app size and its vector, so no need to provide size. and you can chage from xml file too.

Comment: Check out this answer please. It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/31547261/5846135

Comment: Thank you. I put the images in all the drawable folders. Its smooth now. Ill use glide or picasso from now for images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tabbed activity,(2048 * 1152) this resolution is too large. Use Picasso or other Glide library to resize your image.

```
Picasso.with(this)
                .load("url Address")
            //  .loadFromResource(R.drwable.your_image)  
                .resize(200,200)
                .into(imageView);
```

and dont forget to add dependecy in gradle.

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```